# Trying to use ffi and typhoeus gems on windows but I need libcurl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, libcurl

I'm pretty new to rails and I'm trying to get an application working. It's currently using ffi and typhoeus which need a version of libcurl. How can I install a version of libcurl for Windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's one option I implemented but couldn't install only libcurl packages. Cygwin provides lots of the packages and libraries used for development in Linux for being installed on Windows (included curl, libcurl, libcurl-dev, etc).

http://www.cygwin.com/

It worked for me in windows 7 64 bit OS.

Here's another solution for that specific gem

https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/pull/151/files

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Answer that worked for me was:

1. Download cURL from the following URL: https://curl.haxx.se/windows/ (I chose 64bit because that's the system I'm using)
2. Go into the archive and browse to `/bin`
3. Locate `libcurl_x64.dll` (it may be just `libcurl.dll`)
4. Extract to your local drive
5. Rename it to `libcurl.dll` if it has the `_x64` suffix
6. Cut + paste the file into the `/bin` directory of your Ruby installatio

It should work after this